# Making all properties required in a Json Schema object

Tags: java, json, maven, schema

I have a schema file that is being converted to a JSONObject, and i need to take that schema read through all the properties and add them to the appropriate required JSONArray in the schema object.

Currently i am trying to do this recursively, so that it is versatile.

This is the schema file:

```
{
  "$id": "https://*****/test1.schema.json",
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties":{
    "id":{
      "type":"integer"
    }
    "name":{
      "type":"string"
    }
  },
  "required" :["id","test"],
  "additionalProperties" : "false"
}
```

Here is my current code:

```java
public static void newSchema(JSONObject jsonObject){
 List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> keys = ArrayList<>();
 jsonObject.keys()forEachReamaining(keys::add);

 keys.forEach(key->{
  if(keyShouldbeReturned(key))//Ignoring certain keys as i only want whats inside properties {
   output.add(key);
  }
  newSchema(jsonObject.get(key));
 });

 if(!output.isEmpty()){
 JSONArray requiredFields = new JSONArray(output);
 jsonObject.put("required", requiredFields);
 }
}
```

This is really close but the out come is like this

```
{
  "$id": "https://*****/test1.schema.json",
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties":{
    "id":{
      "type":"integer"
    }
    "name":{
      "type":"string"
    }
  "required" :["name","id"],
  },
  "required" :["id","test"],
  "additionalProperties" : "false"
}
```

The Required JSONArray after the properties Object is what needs to be filled, but instead adding it inside that. When i debug i see that it is inside that object, but need help figuring out a way to add it one step up of the current object it is inside.